# ¿Como hacer un mensaje de error personalizado?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Quiero hacer un mensaje de error personalizado, pero no utilizando el `alert` de `Javascript`, sino la `API` de validación de formulario.

Esperando que cuando la persona no llene un `input` salga una nube pidiendo que llene el elemento en cuestión, lo que he leído dice que tengo que usar `setCustomValidity` pero no me muestra el resultado.

En este link está el código:

https://codepen.io/nabux/pen/xpOaGd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `input`, `select` y `textarea` posee la propiedad `validity`, la cual es un objeto del tipo [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)

Un ejemplo de como utilizar [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) podría ser el siguiente:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  this.setCustomValidity('');
});
select.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
  // Required
  if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor seleccione el nivel!');
  }
});

var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  this.setCustomValidity('');
});
input.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
  // Required
  if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor complete el nombre!');
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" required/>
  <select id="select" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="administrador">Administrador</option>
    <option value="limitada">Limitada</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Validar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si los input no tienen el atributo de required no fuciona el script?

Comment: En mi ejemplo solo usé `required`, pero no es el único atributo que se puede usar para validar un `input`. Si entras a leer la documentación para [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) vas a encontrar que error responde a que atributo.

Answer (score 2):

Para eso puedes usar el atributo `required`

Trabaja con input del tipo  types: `text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio`, y `file`

Para personalizar el mensaje, podrías usar la etiqueta  `title`

Por ejemplo con estos datos sería:

```html
<form>
  <label for="txtnombre">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtnombre" name="txtnombre" required     title="Debes rellenar el campo Nombre">
  <button type="submit">Validar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: En `Google Chrome v63.0.3239.108` no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer la validación desde el HTML, por ejemplo:

```
<label for="ctauser1">Cuenta de usuario 1</label>
<input type="text" id="ctauser1" name="ctauser1" required pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Sólo se acepta caracteres">
```

Comment: Interesante tu trabajo sea, pero la verdad me gustaría poder usar la API de formulario para hacer los mensajes

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, tengo una duda por que usas # para referirse al chechbox?, Por cierto esto me puede ayudar con la duda que tengo

Comment: El # o id se refiere para que dentro de la etiqueta `label` pueda clickearse como si fuera un checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez buscas esto.Suerte con el enlace.

http://jsfiddle.net/X8UXQ/121/

Comment: Como sugerencia, podrías agregar el código para ejecutarlo en S.O. en vez de solo agregar un link sin mayor explicación.